# bash script to duplicate file in place changing the name

Tags: bash

This is a quite simple script I would assume but my bash skills are non-existent.

I have a file named `file_name_01.txt` and I need to generate a number `N` of files identical to this one (ie: duplicates) but changing the names so the endings are in ascending order. The resulting files will be named like so:

```
file_name_02.txt
file_name_03.txt
...
file_name_09.txt
file_name_10.txt
...
file_name_N.txt
```

How can I generate such a script?

Comment: What is the question and what have you done so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
for i in {2..20}; do cp file_name_01.txt $(printf 'file_name_%02d.txt' $i); done
```

Replace "20" with whatever your N value is.  That command is equivalent to:

```
cp file_name_01.txt file_name_02.txt
cp file_name_01.txt file_name_03.txt
cp file_name_01.txt file_name_04.txt
cp file_name_01.txt file_name_05.txt
cp file_name_01.txt file_name_06.txt
cp file_name_01.txt file_name_07.txt
cp file_name_01.txt file_name_08.txt
cp file_name_01.txt file_name_09.txt
cp file_name_01.txt file_name_10.txt
cp file_name_01.txt file_name_11.txt
cp file_name_01.txt file_name_12.txt
cp file_name_01.txt file_name_13.txt
cp file_name_01.txt file_name_14.txt
cp file_name_01.txt file_name_15.txt
cp file_name_01.txt file_name_16.txt
cp file_name_01.txt file_name_17.txt
cp file_name_01.txt file_name_18.txt
cp file_name_01.txt file_name_19.txt
cp file_name_01.txt file_name_20.txt
```

Comment: Marking this one as accepted since I find it easier to read. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using `xargs`

```
printf "%s\0" file_name_{02..11}.txt | xargs -0 -L 1 -I {} cp file_name_01.txt {}
```